# Presto - Convert Table into Map

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I would like to convert the below table into a map with multiple key/value pairs

| label_a | label_b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |

into

{'label_a' -> 1, 'label_b' -> 2}

{'label_a' -> 3, 'label_b' -> 4}

{'label_a' -> 5, 'label_b' -> 6}

What would be the easiest way to do this?

All the results I've found are scala/non-presto solutions and I'm not sure how it translates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a map with [`map_from_entries`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html?#map_from_entries):

```sql
WITH data(label_a, label_b) AS (
    VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
)
SELECT map_from_entries(array[('label_a', label_a), ('label_b', label_b)])
FROM data
```

Comment: wow I feel like I tried almost everything except the most basic implementation of map_from_entries.. thanks!